# Unescaping multiple values in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the code to escape special characters:

```
function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
```

How can I unescape the special characters to get the original strings?

I am getting confused with use of / and //.

Comment: how about returning an array from the function that contains the original string and the escaped version?

Comment: I have a pretty strong feeling that this is a case of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Whay do you want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty easy, you can use another function that removes the `\` characters.

```
// Use this to escape
function escapeRegExp(string){
    return string.replace(/([\.\*\+\?\^\$\{\}\(\)\|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}

// And this to unescape
function unescapeRegExp(string) {
    return string.replace(/\\([\.\*\+\?\^\$\{\}\(\)\|\[\]\/\\])/g, "$1")
}

// EXAMPLE:
escapeRegExp(".?[]");
> "\.\?\[\]"

unescapeRegExp("\.\?\[\]");
> ".?[]"
```

PS: I corrected your original function, the regular expression was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you've take this from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

All you need to revert escaping is to remove every odd occurence of `\` character.

```
function unescapeRegExp(string) {
    return string.replace(/\\(.)/g, '$1');
}
```

Comment: This will unescape ANY character. The OP asked for a function to unescape special characters only.

Comment: He wants to get original string from escaped version. So `s === unescapeRegExp(escapeRegexp(s))`